# Django : fetch template from a parallel directory

Tags: django, django-templates

in my project, my template folder is as follows.
In both the folders, i have a template named results.html

```
templates
    |--customer_site
    |       |--results.html
    |
    |backoffice
            |--results.html
```

for the customer facing site, my settings file contains

```
TEMPLATES = [{
...
    'DIRS': ['templates/customer_site'],
}]
```

in one particular function in customer facing site, i need to access the template named results.html which is in backoffice.

```
def some_function(request):
    ....
    ....
    return render(request, 'results.html')
```

this returns the results.html page of customer facing site, but i want the results.html page available in backoffice folder.

Comment: why just not set `DIRS`  route as templates instead? that why you can just point to `/backoffice/results.html` in your view

Comment: This is the ideal solution but I'm at the final stages of my project and I've got multiple templates with same names but different layouts, hence cannot do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**
You can either set your static route to the main templates folder(that is the standard way of doing and what i'm prefer):

```
TEMPLATES = [{
...
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
}]
```

And in your view:

```
  //modify other views to use customer_site/results.html 
  return render(request, 'backoffice/results.html')
```

**Method 2:**
add another path folder to DIRS:

```
 'DIRS': [
            'templates/customer_site',
            'templates/backoffice'
        ],
```

for this to work you need to change your `results.html` file name in backoffice so it doesn't match the one in `customer_site`. Change it to something like `backoffice_results.html`

so if it can't find from `templates/customer_site` then it will go to next template_dirs

```
return render(request, 'backoffice_results.html')
```

Comment: this is what i had initially tried, but for some reason, this throws an error stating "TemplateDoesNotExist"

Comment: @IrfanHarun i had updated method 2 to another way of doing it

Comment: Thank you, i ended up using method 2 and it worked just fine.